# Can't change the log size in Event Viewer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to make the Application log smaller. I cleared the log. The maximum log size is set to 102400 kb. I clicked down to decrement the size and every time I click Apply, I get the error below. What's wrong with the sizes it's choosing? It's decrementing by 4k chunks which should be valid so why is it complaining?

The Maximum Log Size specified is not valid. It is too large or too small. The Maximum Log Size will be set to the following:  102400 KB

Comment: Sounds like you still have one of two GPO policies set.  Are you the Administrator for this server?

Comment: It's a home computer. No domains involved. I am the admin.

Comment: Home or Professional?

Comment: Enterprise. What difference does it make? The ability to change log size is not restricted to type of Windows 10.

Comment: It makes a difference; The ability to configure the size of the log through one of two GPO policies, is restricted by the edition of Windows your using; but I can’t help you.

Comment: Again, if it's a standalone not part of a domain computer, what difference does the edition make? If I answered it's home edition, what was your answer going to be?

Comment: The GPO editor isn’t available on Windows 10 Home.  Which edition you were using was going to change how my answer was going to be written.

Comment: The absence of the GPO editor doesn't cause the log size to not be able to be modified. That's why I asked and that's why I said Windows edition doesn't matter.

Comment: You are absolutely right